# How to enable the 64bit compatibility on IIS 6?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, 64-bit

I´m trying to enable 64bit compatiblity on IIS 6 for 64bit ASP.NET applications. I found instructions in several places but doesn´t works.

Perhaps you can help me, thanks!

Comment: What version of ASP.NET? What instructions have you tried (any links)

Comment: This question would be better suited for the webmaster site. Voted to move it there.

Comment: Is your machine / os 64bit capable ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" covers a lot of potential issues. Did it give you an error message? Did it crash? Did aliens from the planet zwrghh invade and steal 32 of your server's bits so that it can no longer process 64 bit code? More detail helps us to help you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know *How to switch between the 32-bit versions of ASP.NET 1.1 and the 64-bit version of ASP.NET 2.0 on a 64-bit version of Window*, aka  how to enable a 64-bit application pool in IIS 6.0, the document you want is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435

Also note:

> IIS 6.0 supports both the 32-bit mode
>   and the 64-bit mode. However IIS 6.0
>   does not support running both modes at
>   the same time on a 64-bit version of
>   Windows.